# sql query generated by user selects

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am a begginer and I can’t find a tutorial or an example of a dynamic sql query generated from user selects. Suppose I have checkboxes or select fields with `5 colors` and `5 clothes` types. To automatically search for example `“BLUE” “T-SHIRT”` ,do I have to pass using Ajax the values of `“colour”` and `“type”` to a search.php page , and to create the sql query something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colour=”REQUEST_[‘colour’]” 
AND type=”REQUEST_[‘type’]” ?
```

Is this the correct procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the values through a POST/GET AJAX or just straight form. It's your choice.

But the PHP code would be.

```
<?php
$colour = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['colour'])); //Or $_GET
$type = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])); //Or $_GET
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `colour`='".$color."' AND `type`='".$type."'");
```

I suppose this is just my way of doing it.